# Gosu, how to detect when key is pressed?

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I want to move my character left and right when the player is pressing Left cursor or right cursor.

How do I detect in the `update` function in Gosu when a key is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to detect when a button is pressend.

#### Using the event listener

- [Gosu::Window#button_down](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/master/Gosu%2FWindow:button_down)

> This method is called before #update if a button is pressed while the window has focus.

Ideal when you want to trigger something only in the moment the button pass from released to pressed (shoot, jump, ...)

#### Checking is the button is down in this frame

- [Gosu.button_down?](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/master/Gosu#button_down%3F-class_method)

> Returns whether the button `id` is currently pressed

Ideal when you want to keep doing something as far the key is still pressed (moving, ...)

---

Here is a code that contains both systems:

```
class MyGame < Gosu::Window
  def initialize
    @x = 100
    @y = 100
    @velocity = 3
  end

  def button_down(button_id)
    case button_id
    when Gosu::KB_ESCAPE
      close
    when Gosu::KB_SPACE
      shoot
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def update
    move_left if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::KB_LEFT
    move_right if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::KB_RIGHT
    move_up if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::KB_UP
    move_down if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::KB_DOWN
  end

  def shoot
    puts "Shoot!"
  end
  
  def move_left
    @x -= @velocity
  end
  
  def move_right
    @x += @velocity
  end
  
  def move_up
    @y -= @velocity
  end
  
  def move_down
    @y += @velocity
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Gosu.button_down?()](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/master/Gosu#button_down%3F-class_method)

```
Gosu.button_down?(Gosu::<BUTTON>)
```

Here is the list of [BUTTON constants](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/master/Gosu).